# Defining how custom datatype handles being passed to a partially applied function

Tags: haskell

I have a type `Coin`:

```
data Coin = Coin Int deriving (Show)
```

I want to be able to divide an amount of type `Int` by the coin and obtain the whole number result. Since coins can only ever be whole numbers, I've decided to make the Coin type an instance of the `Integral` typeclass:

```
instance Integral Coin where
  div x (Coin y) = Coin (div x y)
```

So a partially applied `div` function can still take in a `Coin` type. However, when I try to compile I get

```
Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Coin'
In the first argument of `div', namely `x'
In the first argument of `Coin', namely `(div x y)'
```

Not sure where I'm going wrong. What I want to be able to do is this:

```
div 100 (Coin 25) -- evaluated to 4
```

Answer (score 1):

The general type for `div` is

```
> :t div
div :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
```

in your instance, you picked `a` to be `Coin`. However this forces the two arguments to have the same type `Coin`.

If you want a division function with heterogeneous arguments, you have to define your own custom function, and avoid `div`.

```
divCoins :: Int -> Coin -> Coin
divCoins x (Coin y) = Coin (div x y)
```

(I'm still puzzled by "dividing an integer by coins" when the vice versa looks more natural to me, but I don't know your aim.)

If we want to be picky, `div 100 (Coin 5)` could be made to type check by adding a `Num Coin` instance so that `100` can be of type `Coin`. I'm not sure if this is a good idea, though. Without knowing the intended usage of `Coin`, I'd avoid this.

---

Edit: I forgot that `Integral` requires `Num`, as @leftaroundabout points out below.

Comment: Indeed. Though to define an `Integral` instance, one _needs_ to first define a `Num` one, which is another reason to stay away from corrumping `div` for this purpose.

Comment: Can you include an example of how to solve this problem?

Comment: @dopatraman: you've already solved it yourself: use the same definition you wrote for `div`. Just give it a proper name of its own instead of trying to instantiate this existing `Integral` method.